# Compression of PNG

Tags: php, image, gdlib

I have this piece of code for uploading images. It makes thumbnails with PNG extension with level 9 compression, but the images do not look good. I want just -50% or little more compression of PNG with transparency.

```
$path_thumbs = "../pictures/thumbs/";
$path_big = "../pictures/";
$img_thumb_width = 140; // 
$extlimit = "yes"; 
$limitedext = array(".gif",".jpg",".png",".jpeg",".bmp");       
$file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!is_uploaded_file($file_tmp)){
    echo "choose file for upload!. <br>--<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">return</a>";
    exit(); 
}

$ext = strrchr($file_name,'.');
$ext = strtolower($ext);
if (($extlimit == "yes") && (!in_array($ext,$limitedext))) {
    echo "dissallowed!  <br>--<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">return</a>";
    exit();
}

$getExt = explode ('.', $file_name);
$file_ext = $getExt[count($getExt)-1];
$rand_name = md5(time());
$rand_name= rand(0,10000);
$ThumbWidth = $img_thumb_width;

if($file_size){
    if($file_type == "image/pjpeg" || $file_type == "image/jpeg"){
        $new_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp);
    }elseif($file_type == "image/x-png" || $file_type == "image/png"){
        $new_img = imagecreatefrompng($file_tmp);
    }elseif($file_type == "image/gif"){
        $new_img = imagecreatefromgif($file_tmp);
    }

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);
    $imgratio = $width/$height;

    if ($imgratio>1){
        $newwidth = $ThumbWidth;
        $newheight = $ThumbWidth/$imgratio;
    }else{
        $newheight = $ThumbWidth;
        $newwidth = $ThumbWidth*$imgratio;
    }
    if (@function_exists(imagecreatetruecolor)){
        $resized_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    }else{
        die("Error: Please make sure you have GD library ver 2+");
    }
    imagecopyresized($resized_img, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    ImagePng ($resized_img, "$path_thumbs/$rand_name.$file_ext,9");
    ImageDestroy ($resized_img);
    ImageDestroy ($new_img);
}

move_uploaded_file ($file_tmp, "$path_big/$rand_name.$file_ext");
```

Answer (score 1):

For better better quality of the resized image, you should use [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)  instread of [`imagecopyresized`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php).

For image transparency you should look at [`imagesavealpha`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php).
To make it work, you need to enable it, before you resize the image and you also need to disable alpha blending. It's best, to put it just after `imagecreatetruecolor`.

```
$resized_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagealphablending($resized_img, false);
imagesavealpha($resized_img, true);
```

As for the size, you have a typo in your code

```
ImagePng ($resized_img,"$path_thumbs/$rand_name.$file_ext,9");
```

should be

```
ImagePng ($resized_img, "$path_thumbs/$rand_name.$file_ext", 9);
```

you put your compression level parameter into the filename instead of the function.

And compression level here doesn't mean it will make your filesize much smaller. It's a tradeoff between speed and filesize.
There is a limit how much you can losslessly compress a file.
If filesize is a concern, you should compress it with lossy compression like JPEG.

Comment: I'm going to use PNG.Can you help where to add Imagesavealpha ?

Answer (score 0):

I think (I did not verify) that you should use the function [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopyresampled.php) instead of imagecopyresize. I think imagecopyresampled has a higher quality. You might also want to start of by using [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php)